# Can we approximate Riemann zeta function in the half strip using its universality principe?

Tags: approximation, riemann-zeta, universal-property

[Universality of Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_universality) , Which related to  the approximation of every Holomorphic function $f(z)$ by Riemann zeta function in the strip , it states for lower density:

> **Corollary**: Let $K_0$ be a compact set in the right half of the critical stripe $1/2< \Re z<1$.
> Let $f$ be a continuous function on $K_0$, which is holomorphic on an open set containing $K_0$ and  does not have any zeros in $K_0$ . For every $\epsilon_0>0$, we have that the limit (lower density )
> $$ \inf\lim\limits_{T \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{T} \lambda \Big (\{ t\in[0,T]: \max\limits_{z \in K_0} \left| {\zeta(z+it) -f(z) )}\right| < \epsilon_0\Big\}) $$
> is positive for $\lambda$ being the Lebesgue measure.

Now my question here : Can we approximate Riemann zeta function in the helf strip by the same strategy by means using that Corollary (lower density) since it is holomorphic ?

**Note**:The part of this question is montioned as an answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/365723/51189)

Comment: if you prove RH sure you can do it on any compact in the right half of the strip, but the universality of RZ applies only to functions without zeroes on $K_0$; however you can use the Davenport Heilbronn function (or others) who have same universality property to approximate any function - lots and lots of functions (Including $L$ functions and their linear combinations) have the universality property, some for all functions, some for functions that have no zeroes

Comment: see this survey (which gives many references - pdf file download) https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjp2_iMmdTqAhVHVc0KHcQLCvIQFjAEegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.nagoya-u.ac.jp%2F~kohjimat%2FNicchuu13.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2iXONes3HdZvySBKhQ685v